# Lists "Looking and removing items in a list"

Tags: python, list, items

Now, I am practicing with lists, So I created 2 lists, so basically I search in one of them for values that are not in the second list and if it is not there I want to remove it from the list. But the results do not have all the entries removed.

Here is what I have done:

```
vocales = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
found = ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
for i in found:
    if i not in  vocales:
        print(i, end=" ")
        print(i not in vocales,end=" ")
        found.remove(i)
        print(found)
        input("press enter to continue")
```

So when in run the program all the consonants are  not recognized

Here is the result:

```
b True ['a', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
h True ['a', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
  True ['a', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'l', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
m True ['a', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'l', 'c', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
s True ['a', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'l', 'c', 'e', 't']
press enter to continue
```

But if I run the code without removing any value from the list, it recognizes all the letters.

```
vocales = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
found = ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
for i in found:
    if i not in  vocales:
        print(i, end=" ")
        print(i not in vocales,end=" ")
        print(found)
        input("press enter to continue")
```

and this is the result:

```
b True ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
h True ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
l True ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
  True ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
c True ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
m True ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
s True ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue 
t True ['a', 'b', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'l', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'e', 's', 't']
press enter to continue
```

All consonants are recognized, could you advice how you could remove of the items that don't appear in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension.

```py
found = [x for x in found if x not in vocales]
```